# Install Rpm Package on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, rpm, kali-linux

I need to install .rpm package in Kali linux.

But shows command not found error.

i tried using with sudo but didn't help.

Does kali supports .rpm files?
How can i install .rpm on Kali linux?

Comment: Which rpm package do you nee to install? Just curious!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[RPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) packages are precompiled and built for `Red Hat Based Linux Distribution` and can be installed only using `yum`, `Zypper` and *RPM* based package managers.
Since *Kali Linux* is based on *Debian* you can not install *RPM* packages directly using `apt` or `dpkg` package managers.

However, you can try a utility called [Alien](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_%28software%29) which can convert one package format into other but **this doesn't mean every RPM will work** since packages link to another packages for dependencies and this can cause troubles.

To install *Alien* and necessary package, run this command

```
$ sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
```

To convert a package from *RPM* to *debian* format, use this command:

```
$ sudo alien packagename.rpm
```

To install the package:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

Comment: so, those that mean i can install yum on kali and install .rpm file?

Comment: **No, I wouldn't recommend it** . You probably could compile `yum` from sources but you wouldn't have any Debian compatible repositories to handle. Just try alien and install *rpm* you want to install or find its equivalent *deb* package.